# PKCS11 - SHA1HMAC yields a different SHA1HMAC result

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, pkcs#11, hsm, pkcs11interop

I am following the below steps to compute the HMAC using SHA1 algorithm using two different API and both the outputs are not matching.

1)  I first compute HMAC for a given data and key using SHA1 algorithm through **BouncyCastle API**.

2)  We compute HMAC for the data and key inside the HSM(Thales) using **PKCS11 API(Pkcs11Interop)**.

When we compared the results of 1 and 2 the data does not match.

**Bouncy Castle code:**

```
        HMAC hmac = HMACSHA1.Create();

        String key = "BC55B4580589775F887890A7ACA5E624";

        hmac.Key = Util.HexStringToByteArray(key);

        byte[] modInput = Util.HexStringToByteArray("000000000000000000000006000080012b0601040181e438010102041603");

        String ki = Util.ByteArrayToHexString(hmac.ComputeHash(modInput));
```

**PKCS11 code:**

```
       ObjectHandle k = FindObjectByLabel(keyLabel);//same key as above

       Mechanism m = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_SHA_1_HMAC);

      **//We have verified that both key and data value are the same**
      return mSession.Connection.Sign(m, k, data);
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: What were the two outputs? How did you compare the two keys and data values?

Comment: Could you please create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) console app that imports the key into HSM, then uses the same key for HMAC operation via both APIs and compares the result?